# Upload a file using TFS Client APIs

Tags: asp.net, api, file-upload, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to upload a file from asp.net webpage to TFS server.
Using TFS API I have created bug from my web page - but the bug also needs a file attachement to upload please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply create an Attachment object and add it to the Attachments collection on the WorkItem before you save it:

```
Dim attachment As New Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Attachment("c:\somefile.txt", "My Comment")
workItem.Attachments.Add(attachment)
workItem.Save()
```