# How to programmatically attach a file to TFS work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I want attach a file to a work item of type `bug`. While saving bug details to server I have this attachment.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860495/upload-a-file-using-tfs-client-apis

Answer (score 8):

```
TeamFoundationServer server = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("TFSRTM08");
WorkItemStore store = (WorkItemStore)server.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
WorkItem workItem = store.Projects["ABC"].WorkItemTypes["Bug"].NewWorkItem();
//Set other work item properties.
workItem.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\Temp\MyAttachment.txt", "Comment About Attachment"));
workItem.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [download the Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b&DisplayLang=en), there should be an example in there for working with [Work Items and attachments using the TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130335.aspx).