# Paste screenshot into TFS 2010 Web access for bugs

Tags: tfs

Is there anyway to automatically paste screenshots into TFS 2010 Web access for bugs?  I don't want to have to save the screenshots into files and then add them as an attachment.  This takes a while to do this.  I just want to quickly add them to the bug.

Comment: You can do this with [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com/tfs) - adding new bugs (including screenshots) is a breeze together with TFS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

See this similar (possibly not identical) question on MSDN forums:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/fe8b80c9-8fbd-4d6c-bc65-80d75dd3409b/

In response to:

> Now, when adding the task into TFS 2010 , I can use the cupboard to “copy/Paste” from OneNote to TFS.  But then the image is stored as a link to my local machine and not stored in TFS server.

The answer was (repeatedly stated):

> As I said in my previous reply, we should to add the images as attachment into Work Items. Open Work Item in VS, click Attachments tab, then click Add to browse your images, the images will store in TFS Server.

**Or, DIY and write an application**

TFS exposes an API that you could use to create your own tool, rather than using their web access.  See this question for how to implement that particular piece (adding attachments):

[Upload a file using TFS Client APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860495/upload-a-file-using-tfs-client-apis)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can go to the Attachments Tab and paste your screenshot using CTRL-V.
An attachment called 'screenshot.png' will automatically be created.

Comment: That's using Visual Studio - the question is about doing the same thing using TFS web access